# mongoose Error: cyclic dependency detected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, video-intelligence-api

I wrote a service that analyses videos with [Google Cloud Video Intelligence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/video-intelligence)

And I save the analysis results to the MongoDB with mongoose

This is the model I use (I've simplified everything to avoid confusion):

```
// Video.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    analysis_progress: {
        percent: { type: Number, required: true },
        details: {}
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['idle', 'processing', 'done', 'failed'],
        default: 'idle'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema);
```

When analyse operation ends, I call the function below and run `update` like this:

```
function detectFaces(video, results) {
   //Build query
    let update = {
        $set: {
            'analysis_results.face_annotations': results.faceDetectionAnnotations // results is the the test result
        }
    };

    Video.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: video._id }, update, { new: true }, (err, result) => {
        if (!err)
            return console.log("Succesfully saved faces annotiations:", video._id);
        throw err // This is the line error thrown
    });
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (C:\Users\murat\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bycape\media-analysis-api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:333:34)
    at serializeInto (C:\Users\murat\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bycape\media-analysis-api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17)
...
```

Solutions I tried:

1. Added `{autoIndex: false}` inside db config.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, autoIndex: false });
```

2. Removing `retryWrites=true` from Mongo URI structure. (I didn't have that parameter in my connection URI already)

So, I think the source of the problem is that I am saving the whole test result but I don't have any other option to do that. I need to save as it is.

I am open to all kinds of suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as I guessed, the problem was that there was a `cyclic dependency` in the object that came to me from google.

With help of my colleague:

> Then since JSON.stringify() changes an object into simple types:
> string, number, array, object, boolean it is not capable of storing
> references to objects therefor by using stringify and then parse you
> destroy the information that stringify cannot convert.
>
> Another way would be knowing which field held the cyclic reference and
> then unsetting, or deleting that field.

I couldn't find which field has `cycylic dependency` so I used I `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()` to remove it.

```
let videoAnnotiations = JSON.stringify(operationResult.annotationResults[0]);
videoAnnotiations = JSON.parse(videoAnnotiations);
```